# How to do a async function in a controller with a node API

Tags: node.js, routes, async-await

I'm stuck I'd like to get all the ratings for a fablab and can't get the code to be asynchronous.
So here I get an empty array since the code is not async.

This is my example :

```js
// get all ratings for a fablab
rating_router.get('/get/:id', (req, res) => {
  Fablab.findById({_id:req.params.id}, (err, fablab) => {
    if(err) send(err)
    else {

      let ratingstest = []
      fablab.rating.map(ratingID =>  {
        Rating.findById({_id:ratingID}, (err, rating) => {
          if(err) send(err)
          else ratingstest.push(rating)
        })
      })

      return ratingstest
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could add a conditional to check when the last query resolves and then pass the array of results to `res.send`:

```
rating_router.get('/get/:id', (req, res) => {
  Fablab.findById({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, fablab) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err)
    }
    else {
      let ratingstest = []

      fablab.rating.forEach(ratingID => {
        Rating.findById({ _id: ratingID }, (err, rating) => {
          if (err) {
            res.send(err)
          }
          else {
            ratingstest.push(rating)

            // Check if this is the last one
            if (ratingstest.length == fablab.rating.length) {
              res.send(ratingstest)
            }
          }
        })
      })
    }
  })
})
```

However, it might be nicer to use promises:

```
rating_router.get('/get/:id', (req, res) => {
  Fablab
    .findById({ _id: req.params.id })
    .then(fablab => fablab.rating || [])
    .then(ratingIDs => ratingIDs.map(ratingID =>
      Rating.findById({ _id: ratingID })
    ))
    .then(ratingArr => Promise.all(ratingArr))
    .then(result => res.send(result))
    .catch(err => res.send(err))
})
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Inside mapping function, make findById promise

```
function findByIdPromise(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        Rating.findById({_id:ratingID}, (err, rating) => {
            if(err) reject(err)
            else {
                ratingstest.push(rating)
                resolve()
            }
        })
    })
}
```

After mapping is done, you'll have array of promises, then just do

`Promise.all(fablab.rating).then(()=>console.log(ratingstest)`)

Comment: Sorry, it send me an empty array. Thanks anyway